# How can I add src/main/resources to the classpath when using mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run the following application which attempts to load a file (`src/main/resources/test.txt`) from the classpath:

```
package com.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("test.txt"));
    }
}
```

When I do `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.Main`, I get `null` printed out on the command line.

So how do I get the files in src/main/resources added to the classpath?  Note that I ran `mvn package`, checked the generated `target/test.jar`, and confirmed that it included `test.txt` at the top level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slash should solve it

```
System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("/test.txt"));
```

Your code would work if you placed the test.txt file under:

```
src/main/resources/com/example
```

Comment: If you put the test.txt into the com/example package it will not work. To get that working correctly you need to put the test.txt into src/main/resources nothing else.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand now. So `getResource` interprets paths relative to the class instance (so since `Main` is in `com.example` I was accidentally looking for `src/main/resources/com/example/test.txt` instead of `src/main/resources/test.txt`)